# Identify a Plant, that killed the original small tree

Tags: identification

we had this little tree in a Pot and after a while there grew a green Stark. Over 3 Months the tree died and only the stark grew further.

And now a Year and a half later there grew this  thingy and no one knows what it is. You great people are my Last Hope.

[image: Full Picture]
[image: Leaf]
[image: Closeup of broken Leaf]

Further Details:

1. Is standing on the Sunny Side.
2. Temperatur 22-25C
3. Watered once a Week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plant is a succulent type. It thrives on little water. It stores its own water. The tree just couldn't compete. If you had watered more, the tree would have lived and this plant would have died. By watering infrequently, this guy thrived and the tree died. This plant did not kill your tree, grins.

[image: Kalanchoe baharensis]
[image: Kalanchoe baharensis out of doors]
[Elephant's ear Kalanchoe](http://Elephant's%20ear%20Kalanchoe%20specs)

Comment: I saw that comment :) - So it is like a cactus? Anything i should know about it? Or just looking how big it will get?

Comment: Being grown in a pot indoors this plant will only be sprawling and gawky.  If I were you, I'd snip the top new leaves off and transplant into potting soil to make a new plant.  The original plant (mother plant) will get thicker and fuller.  The new baby can be in it's own pot cuddled up to mom? Just keep the terminal or apex bud snipped off.  Most of the energy in that plant is in the apex bud.  Snip that off and the energy is reallocated to the rest of the plant.